# What stock character/stereotype/thing does Cab Calloway imitate near the beginning of this 1950s "music video"?

Tags: meaning, jazz, live-music, dancing

Source: https://youtu.be/8mq4UT4VnbE?t=22

Ever since I first saw this performance of *Minnie the Moocher*, I've been wondering what that means. He is walking stiffly with his upper body with strange leg movements while "brushing" part of his chest with one hand, the other hand's index finger pointing straight down, culminating in a Michael Jackson-esque leg movement (obviously MJ was inspired by him and not the other way around).

My first thought was that he was imitating a rich man with a monocle or something, but that doesn't seem to hold up.

Is it maybe just supposed to "look funny and unusual"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about dance and not music.

Comment: Relevant meta question: [Are question about dance/dancers on-topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/585/3955)

Comment: The "brushing" is stylistically buffing his fingernails.  Beyond that, it's just kind of dance.

Comment: @Duston Buffing his fingernails and then examining them to check out how he did.

Comment: (I just want to disagree with Pied Piper above as this being off-topic, because it's interesting regardless. The whole zoot suit thing was huge at one time and anyone interested in historical pop culture music of that era might want to learn more about it. Jazz is a big influence on today's music.

Answer (score 4):

This is a style from the '40s.  Cab here is emulating a hepcat with how they typically walked.  Hepcats were known for wearing Zoot Suits.  Please read some of the book [*The Power of the Zoot: Youth Culture and Resistance During World War II*](https://books.google.com/books?id=e6gwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=Cab%20Calloway%20hepcat%20zoot&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZobLY667nAhVCmuAKHZo_BRsQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=Cab%20Calloway%20hepcat%20zoot&f=false) by Luis Alvarez with keywords highlighted.

Also, this style of how young men carried themselves can be seen in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vaihriTY68) ("The Big Bad Wolf") from the Bugs Bunny cartoon movie *The Looney, Looney, Looney Bugs Bunny Movie*.  There were a few cartoons from Looney Tunes devoted to this hepcat culture.  This example is just one.

Tom and Jerry also had some cartoons reflecting this culture.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAuLONmIof0) is *The Zoot Cat* (1944), showing Tom dressed in a Zoot suit and acting the part.